# SQL Server : DATEADD value in parameters is returning an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, exec, dateadd

I've built a procedure I need to run it for the last 60 days. I can't seem to figure it out.

I've got the following date parameters statements for the parameters and they return

```
select dateadd(Day, -60, getdate()), dateadd(Day, -1, getdate())
```

[image]

The code itself adjusts the end date to be at the very end of the day. 23:59:59.

When I do this

```
exec LRP_PROC 
         @start_Dt = dateadd(Day, -60, getdate()),
         @end_dt = dateadd(Day, -1, getdate()),
         @mode = 0
```

I get the following error

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not permit arbitrary expressions to be passed as stored procedure parameters.  You need to declare and assign local variables before calling the proc.

eg

```
declare @start datetime = dateadd(Day, -60, getdate());
declare @end datetime = dateadd(Day, -1, getdate());

exec LRP_PROC @start_Dt=@start, @end_dt=@end, @mode = 0;
```